# Apache configuration to serve 2 website and APIs under the same domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, reactjs

I would like to configure Apache in order to have under the same domain:

1. a static website (it is a Single Page Application created with
       create-react-app) deployed in `/var/www/html/ui`
2. a WordPress instance deployed in `/var/www/wordpress/Commdev`
3. some Node.js APIs running on `http://localhost:3000/api`

I would like to have the following URL mapping:

1. `mydomain.com/` -> to the static website
2. `mydomain.com/admin` -> to the WordPress instance (mydomain.com/admin/wp-admin to the Admin Panel of WordPress )
3. `mydomain.com/api` -> proxy the Node.js APIs

This is my initial configuration

```
ServerName 127.0.0.1:80

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyVia Full
<Proxy *>
  Require all granted
</Proxy>

<Location /api>
    ProxyPass        http://localhost:3000/api
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/api
</Location>

Alias /admin /var/www/wordpress/Commdev
<Directory /var/www/wordpress/Commdev>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias / /var/www/html/ui
<Directory /var/www/html/ui>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

How would you address the situation?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This is the final configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.com 
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ui

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
#       ProxyVia Full

        <Location /api>
                ProxyPass        http://localhost:3000/api
                ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/api
        </Location>

        <Location />
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                #AllowOverride None
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        Alias /admin /var/www/wordpress/Commdev
        <Location /admin>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                #AllowOverride All
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from all
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I was getting this error: Invalid command 'ProxyPass'.
But I just enabled the module following this answer
https://superuser.com/a/1544110. in ubuntu 20 and now it works perfectly.